# Unity catalog not enabled on cluster in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

We are trying out Unity catalog in Azure Databricks. We connected a pre-existing workspace to the new metastore.

I created a new catalog. When I run a notebook and try to write to table "myfirstcatalog.bronze.mytable" I get the error

> [UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster.

I have run this both on an pre-existing cluster as well as a newly cluster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem. I had used access mode None, when it needs Single user or Shared.

> To create a cluster that can access Unity Catalog, the workspace you are creating the cluster in must be attached to a Unity Catalog metastore and must use a Unity-Catalog-capable access mode (shared or single user).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/compute

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. So I deleted and recreated my cluster and noticed the second time it had a tag "Unity Catalog". This time it worked.

Also in the admin console when I looked at my workspaces, this one had a `-` in the Metastore column. When I did a hard-refresh (CTRL-F5), the metastore appeared.

Perhaps there was extra time required for it to provision.

Answer (score 0):

[UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster

to resolve this, check below points

1. Check if DBR version greater than 11 is selected
2. Check credential passthrough not enabled
3. Should see a unity_catlog as tag on cluster

Check blog https://medium.com/@gcp.azure.aws/azure-databricks-unity-catalog-set-up-bb501b8f66bc for more details around this topic