# Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm trying to set up Unity Catalog on Databricks and for that purpose I created a new cluster with runtime version 11.3 and Single user as Access Mode. I tried to run

```
%sql
create catalog if not exists playcatdemo
```

from a notebook attached to the cluster I made previously but I get the following error:

> [UC_NOT_ENABLED] Unity Catalog is not enabled on this cluster.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570731/unity-catalog-not-enabled-on-cluster-in-databricks) from this discussion says that I need to set the Access Mode to either Single user or Shared. In my case, I have only two options and those are Single user and No isolation shared. However, I have Single user as a selected so I guess this shouldn't be a problem. Has anyone stumbled upon an issue like this recently and how did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Is Unity Catalog enabled for Workspace?

Comment: Good point. I don't know but I have tried to enable it by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/enable-workspaces#enable-your-workspace-for-unity-catalog but I don't get the `Click the Workspaces tab.` button. This is what my screen looks like: https://i.imgur.com/O8DApZ3.png

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, Which I have enabled metastore after workspace and cluster created, to fix the issue all I had to do to edit the cluster and re-change the databricks run time version to >= 11.3 then I can see Unity Catalog on the right-hand side summary and I'm using personal compute policy with shared access mode. Hopefully this will also fix your issue.

If you haven't create UC then follow these steps:
Your user account should be part of owner role for the databricks resource in Azure/AWS, then you login to databricks workspace and top right hand conner look for manage user under your username and that will redirect to create metastore page then follow these steps to create metastore.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/azure-managed-identities#config-managed-id

Comment: How did you enable the metastore after workspace and cluster creation? The tutorials I follow don't have the same buttons/actions on the UI as I have in my case.

Comment: Your user account should be part of owner role for the databricks resource in Azure/AWS, then you login to databricks workspace and top right hand conner look for manage user under your username and that will redirect to create metastore page then follow these steps to create metastore. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/azure-managed-identities#config-managed-id